# add query result as new column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the result of my query as a new column, this is my code but it shows to be in 2 tables.

```
SELECT JobNo
      ,Prepared1
      ,Prepared2
  FROM [test]
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Prepared1 >1  THEN 1 END) +
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Prepared2 >1 THEN 1 END) as 'Done'
  FROM [test]
GROUP BY JobNo
```

[image: Current result]

What should be my code to have it in 1 table like this

[image: desired result]

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL syntax, it looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it should be sql-server... Thank y'all for the replies...

Answer (score 2):

I think JobNo is `UNIQUE`. if so, you can simply use:

```
SELECT JobNo
      ,Prepared1
      ,Prepared2
      ,CASE WHEN Prepared1 > 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN Prepared2 >1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM [test] t1
```

If not:

```
select JobNo,
    Prepared1,
    Prepared2,
    t2.done
from [test] t1
join (
    select JobNo,
        COUNT(case 
                when Prepared1 > 1
                    then 1
                end) + COUNT(case 
                when Prepared2 > 1
                    then 1
                end) as done
    from [test] t2
    group by JobNo
    ) t2 on t1.JobNo = t2.JobNo;
```